# ERROR : E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main : Caused by: The Facebook sdk must be initialized before calling activateApp

Tags: java, android, android-studio, facebook, sdk

hello everyone i have error in my android/java project

`E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main`

`Caused by: The Facebook sdk must be initialized before calling activateApp`

screenshots:

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGP35.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Xd8s.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue with RAGIP MULLAMUSA's answer (Sorry I don't have enough reputation to vote or comment)

While I tried to upgrade the Facebook SDK from 9.x.x to latest (15.1.0), I found this error:

> The Facebook sdk must be initialized before calling activateApp

I tried to put `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());` before `AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);`, and it doesn't work. But the error will become:

> A valid Facebook app client token must be set in the AndroidManifest.xml or set by calling FacebookSdk.setClientToken before initializing the sdk.

You might obtain the client token from https://developers.facebook.com/, and put it in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

  <application
    android:name=".App"
    ...
    ...>
  
    <meta-data
      android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken"
      android:value="YOUR_FACEBOOK_CLIENT_TOKEN" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Note: You don't need to keep `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());` after putting client token in manifest.

I tried to put `FacebookSdk.setClientToken(YOUR_FACEBOOK_CLIENT_TOKEN);` before `super.onCreate();`, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add any code explaining the problem but after searching for this problem I found that you should add SDK initializes method in your`onCreate()` like the following

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To use Facebook Ads Sdk in your app, You must make an App class for your app and initialize the sdk there.

```java
import android.app.Application;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    }
}
```

And set it in your manifest.

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:name=".App"  <!-- Name of your app class -->
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        ........
        ........

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

slove it by **update gradle** and **add** facebook client token in **manifests**

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken"
android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).